# Constraint for valueType

Tags: c#, .net, constraints

Let's consider this example:

```
private TResult Invoke<TResult>(string identifier, Func<TResult> action)
    where TResult : class, new()
{
    if (!this.IsActive()) {
        // logging
        return new TResult();
    }

    if (this.dataBase.Exists(identifier)) {
        return action();
    } else {
        // some more logging
        return new TResult();
    }
}
```

I've got a generic function which executes `action` and does some additional check I always have to do - which is why I wrote that helper function.

It can be called like this

```
this.Invoke(
    "GetTest",
    () => {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items = this.dataBase.Execute().GetResult().ToList();
        return items;
    });
```

If one of the checks fails, `Invoke` will return an empty `List<string>` in this case.
That works well.

Now, some calls return a value type (such as a boolean) rather than reference type.
In those cases my function doesn't work anymore because I've added the constraint `class` in order to return a default value.

It would work if I removed those constraints and changed the code to return `default` rather than `new TResult()`, but that's not what I need. I don't want to have a null-reference for reference types.

I thought about overloading the `Invoke` method, removing the `constraints`  and changing my code to return `default` but methods can't be overloaded by just changing the constraints.

Of course, I could rename the method, but that doesn't seem to be that nice.

Is there anything else I can do here?

Comment: You can write another method with `where TResult : struct` constraint

Comment: I don't see why you need the `class` constraint at all. You say it's "in order to return a default value" but you can do that just by virtue of the `new()` constraint (which all value types satisfy). Just remove the `class` constraint.

Comment: I'd also note that your sample usage creates a list for no reason (and with a syntax error) - it looks like you could use `this.Invoke("GetTest", () => this.dataBase.Execute().GetResult().ToList());` instead...

Comment: Also small addition about `new`/`struct` constraint - `new Nullable<int>() == null` is `true` =)

Comment: I'm not really sure what it is you're looking to get back from your `Invoke` method - but you might want to simply return a [`Maybe<TResult>`](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1510/maybe-monad-csharp) and then lose the `class` constraint....

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53297088.shtml) hack based on the fact that constraints are not part of the signature, but parameters are, and constraints in parameters are enforced during overload resolution:

```
class RequireStruct<T> where T : struct { }
class RequireClass<T> where T : class { }
    
private TResult Invoke<TResult>(string identifier, Func<TResult> action, RequireClass<TResult> _ = null)
    where TResult : class, new()
{
    return Invoke(identifier, action, () => new TResult());
}

// handle nullable value types
private TResult? Invoke<TResult>(string identifier, Func<TResult?> action)
    where TResult : struct
{
    return Invoke(identifier, action, () => (TResult?)new TResult());
}

private TResult Invoke<TResult>(string identifier, Func<TResult> action, RequireStruct<TResult> _ = null)
    where TResult : struct
{
    return Invoke(identifier, action, () => new TResult());
}

private TResult Invoke<TResult>(string identifier, Func<TResult> action, Func<TResult> def)
{
    // your actual logic goes here
    return def();
}


Invoke("GetTestRef", () => new List<object>()); // empty list
Invoke("GetTestVal", () => 1); // 0
Invoke("GetTestVal", () => (int?)1); // 0
```

Comment: As of C# 8, I believe the hack is no longer required - constraints are taken into account when determining applicable function members.

Comment: @JonSkeet but AFAIK they are still not a part of method signature, so removing this hack will give `CS0111 Type already defines a member called 'Invoke' with the same parameter types` [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyqoAcpsA3AQwww6AFQBKMAM4BXXBjoBJAHa8IAaxgAecVNkYAfAApCpAAx1sAExhKM2AGbYYUNAwCs2iTLn66/MHYQSgCUVACQAO4AFs7COt7yIAzErkowEYahlOyUYYQA7HRpEaJeepkA3FQAvhyU3HyCcWVyiirqWvF6RibmVjZ2js6uhB5dPn4B2EFZkTGwpbqtSZIYUNIBVDl5hcWLCZU1dTVAA=)

Comment: Ah yes, of course - sorry, hadn't thought about that aspect!